# Append elements of an array to another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have some unknown number of iterations in which every iteration gives two arrays.

```
for ($i = 0; $i<sizeof($foo); $i++) {
    $array1 = //do something
    $array2 = //do something
    $result = //($result + $array1 + $array2)
}
```

What I want to do is to append the elements of those arrays to `$result`.

If I use `array_merge()` I cannot add the previous elements of `$result` to it.

If I use `array_push()` I will get a 2D array which I don't want.

`array_push($result, $array1, $array2);`

So what is the best solution to my problem? Is there any way to do it without iterating through each array and pushing every element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution using [***call_user_func_array***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) function:

```
...
$result = call_user_func_array("array_merge", [$result, $array1, $array2]);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have numeric keys, to push a variable number of elements into the result array without creating unwanted depth, use the spread operator with `array_push()` -- it performs better than merging the result array with the other arrays and saving the merged data back into the result array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ovU5d))

```
array_push($result, ...$array1, ...$array2);
```